# How to get the tag and its text using htmlagility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            string html = null;
            html =
            "<body> " +
                "<p class=\"hang12\">“What is Lorem Ipsum?” <i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</i> Lorem Ipsum has been the</p>" +
                "<p class=\"hang12\">when an unknown printer took a galley of type <i>It has survived not only five centuries,</i>.</p>" +
                "<p class=\"hang12\">but also the  <i>remaining essentially </i> </p>" +
                "<p class=\"hang12\">with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, <i>and more recently with desktop</i>. 1944.</p>" +
                "</body>";

            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
            {
                chNodes(item);
            }

public void chNodes(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node)
        {
            try
            {
                if (node.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (var item in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        chNodes(item);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("************");
                    Console.WriteLine(node.Line);
                    Console.WriteLine(node.LinePosition);
                    Console.WriteLine("************");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

My code above get the first position of the opening tag found.  But i can't get the position of the closing tag.  How can i solve it? I need those values to highlight the text in the webbrowser control. thank you.

Comment: Try doing something like Console.WriteLine(node.LinePosition + node.OuterHtml.Length - node.Name.Length - 3);, you may need to adjust the value 3 to something else to get to the exact position and I believe this should work for all the nodes which are having closing tag

Comment: Thank you i didn't realize a solution like that will work

Comment: did it work or not?

Comment: it work. i adjust the code. And your code gave me idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can get using following code try this

```
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='hang12']"))
{ 
     item.innerText;
     item.innerHtml; 
}
```